# Line break on symbol shows hyphen

Tags: gedit

Since the upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04.1 (from 18.04.1) gedit appears to have a new feature for line breaking.

With the preferences "line breaking" and "don't split words across two lines" both activated, gedit splits a line on certain symbols within a string, for example `xyz/abc` will be split after the `/`. Other characters that allow this are for example `|!?`.

However, the editor shows a hyphen symbol `-` when such a split is made. Screenshot:

[image]

To emphasize: I did not type the `-`, I typed `xyz/abc` and this was the output.

This feature is confusing for me, especially when I write programming code, or worse, when I read code written by others, thinking that there is a `-` in the code. Another case is urls in text files, which have a lot of `/` characters, where it looks as if there is a `-` in the url. There is no way to find this out by just looking at the editor, if you type `xyz/-abc` then the output is exactly the same. The only way to find out is to resize the editor window (then the `-` disappears) or to disable line breaking.

Is there a way to switch off this feature?

Answer (score 2):

There are three bugs for this. As far as I can understand, it was initially caused by Pango, which was fixed, but gedit still needs to be fixed to correctly use Pango. (Someone please correct me if this is wrong.)

I suggest that you go to each bug, log in if required, and press the thumbs-up in the first post in the thread.

[Inserting an hyphen at line breaks looks wrong in applications like gedit (1)](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gedit/-/issues/240)

[Inserting an hyphen at line breaks looks wrong in applications like gedit (2)](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/issues/2530)

[Hyphen/dash inserted for text wrapping should be disabled in gedit](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gedit/-/issues/365)

Unfortunately, we're at the mercy of the developers, who don't seem to have taken this seriously. Perhaps we need to raise this as a bug with Ubuntu?